# Get relation of relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the comments of the links with laravel relationship, the comments of links return normally, but I don't know how to get it in view or dd(), how can I do it?

Controller:

```
$page = Page::where('friendly_url', $id)
                ->select('id', 'photo', 'friendly_url', 'name', 'description', 'followers', 'links', 'tag_id', 'links_clicks')
                ->with('ptag', 'links', 'links.comments', 'links.tag')
                ->with(['links.comments.user' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'name', 'lastname');
            }])->with(['links.comments.userProfile' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'photo');
            }])->first();
```

dd($page->getRelation('links')

```
Collection {#301 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Link {#307 ▼
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "comments" => Collection {#316 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▶]
        "tag" => Tag {#322 ▶}
      ]
```

dd($page->getRelation('links')->getRelation('comments'))

```
BadMethodCallException
Method getRelation does not exist.
```

dd($page->getRelation('links')->comments)

```
Exception
Property [comments] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

EDIT:

I want to show the attributes of comment and comment.user, how I can do it?

```
foreach($page->getRelation('links')->pluck('comments') as $comment) {
    dd($comment);             
}

Collection {#327 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Comment {#325 ▼
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "content" => "teste"
        "link_id" => 1
        "user_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2018-01-11 00:47:32"
      ]
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "user" => User {#330 ▼
          #attributes: array:3 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "Halysson"
            "lastname" => "Teves dos Santos"
          ]
        }
        "userProfile" => UserProfile {#326 ▶}
      ]
```

Comment: did you defile relations in model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
foreach($page->links as $link){
         $comments = $link->comments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should define relations first on relevent models and then using 'with' function can load models with relations OR a relation can be called directly by single model see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) for further details

eg: you have defined a relation for user to phone, as user has a phone, one to one relation. in user model define a relation like

```
public function phone()
{
 return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
}
```

now to call this relation on user model instance.

```
$user = User::find(1);
dd($user->phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the `select()` method, you also need to include all the foreign keys in it to allow Eloquent to be able to load these relationships.

But since you just start using Laravel, I'd recommend you to just remove `select()` method from this complex query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the links of a page :

```
$page->links
```

if you want all the comments of a page :

```
$page->links->pluck('comments')
```

that's it :)

Comment: return Collection {#298 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 5
  ]
}

Comment: Can you give an output of what you want to displau ?