# Get relation of relation attributes

Tags: laravel

I want to show the comments of link and show de relations of comments that is user and userprofile...

dd($page->getRelation('links'));

```
Collection {#318 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Link {#317 ▼
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "comments" => Collection {#327 ▼
              #attributes: array:5 [▼
                "id" => 3
                "content" => "teste"
                "link_id" => 1
                "user_id" => 1
                "created_at" => "2018-01-11 00:47:32"
              ]
              #relations: array:2 [▼
                "user" => User {#330 ▶}
                "userProfile" => UserProfile {#326 ▶}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

In the view I put:

```
        @foreach($page->getRelation('links') as $link)
        <div class="link">

    <!--show de comments of link (ONLY FOR EXPLANATION)-->
@foreach()
        <div class="comments">
        SHOW DE ATTRIBUTE OF COMMENT AND ATTRIBUTE OF RELATIONS OF COMMENT (user, userprofile)
        </div>
@endforeach

        </div>

        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation under [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

> Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem. (...) When querying, you may specify which relationships should be eager loaded using the with method.

For example:

```
$pages = App\Page::with("link")->get();

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    echo $page->links->comments;
}
```

You can also eager load multiple relationships

```
$pages = App\Page::with(['link', 'author'])->get();
```

And finally, you can nest eager loading relationship

> o eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For
>   example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the
>   author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement

```
$pages = App\Page::with('link.comments')->get();
```

Comment: [OP already uses eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199315/get-relation-of-relation). You can also see that by looking at the results he posted.

Answer (score 0):

first load the relationships in the controller function:

```
$page = Page::where($allYourConditions)->with(['links' => 
function($query){
  $query->with(['comments' => function($query){
    $query->with(['user', 'userProfile']);
  }]);
}])->get();
```

then in the view file:

```
@foreach($page->links as $link)
  <div class="link">
  @foreach($link->comments as $comment)
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-user">{{$comment->user}}</div>
      <div class="comment-user-profile">{{$comment->userProfile}}</div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```