# Accessing distant relationship with belongstoMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So each user can own multiple pages, and each page can have multiple users (assigned a role), and each page can have a job. Now, I am getting the pages owned by the user(s) like so:

**user.php**

```
/**
 * Get the pages.
 *
 * @return App\Modules\Pages\Entities\Pages
 */
public function pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\Pages\Entities\Pages')->withTimeStamps();
}
```

Now, I am trying to get the user's jobs, that belong to all and any of their pages

I have a relationship on the pages model, where the page can have many jobs like so:

**pages.php**

```
/**
 * Get the jobs.
 *
 * @return App\Modules\Jobs\Entities\Jobs
 */
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->hasmany('App\Modules\Jobs\Entities\Jobs');
}
```

The relationship is like so:

**User table**

```
id | name | password.. etc
```

**Pages table**

```
id | name
```

**Pages pivot table**

```
id | pages_id | user_id
```

**Jobs Table**

```
id | pages_id | name
```

So, my question is: how can I get all of the jobs that belong to all or any of the pages the user owns, or is associated with. I have tried the following:

```
$jobs = User::with('pages.jobs')
    ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

Which just gets the user's table, not the jobs.

Now, I understand I could do the following, but this is resource intensive, and not the way I am looking for:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->pages as $page)
    @foreach($page->jobs as $job)
        // ...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

So, is there anyway to achieve this with a hasmanyThrough, or any other solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get relation of relation attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209459/get-relation-of-relation-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Job::whereHas('page.users', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', auth()->id());
})->get();
```

I assume that these relations are defined. If not, define those. In the `Pages` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\Jobs\Entities\Users');
}
```

In the `Jobs` model:

```
public function page()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Modules\Jobs\Entities\Pages');
}
```

If you do not follow [naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions), you also need to add pivot table name and foreign key names to these relationship definitions.

Comment: That worked, great. May I ask, is there a way to do it with relationships like hasmanythrough etc?

Comment: @Nate no, you can't use `hasManyThrough` and there is no any similar relationship you can use.